# fetch max number of concurrent phone calls from call_log

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help crafting an query in MySQL 5.0.77 that returns the peak number of concurrent phone calls given the data shown below (one day's worth of calls in an office). I simply want to know what is the highest number of people who were on the phone at the same time at any given time throughout the day.

First, here's the MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `call_log` (
`call_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`call_datetime` datetime default NULL,
`call_length` time default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`call_id`)
)
```

I loaded data into the table with this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'call_log_import.csv' INTO TABLE call_log FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINE TERMINATED BY '\n' (call_datetime, call_length);
```

Here is the actual row data in CSV format:

```
2012-11-07 5:28:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 7:04:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 7:04:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 7:04:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 7:25:00,0:00:34
2012-11-07 7:25:00,0:00:37
2012-11-07 7:25:00,0:00:38
2012-11-07 7:30:00,0:00:16
2012-11-07 7:49:00,0:01:29
2012-11-07 7:55:00,0:00:43
2012-11-07 7:55:00,0:00:46
2012-11-07 7:55:00,0:00:46
2012-11-07 8:00:00,0:25:01
2012-11-07 8:00:00,0:00:35
2012-11-07 8:01:00,0:00:35
2012-11-07 8:01:00,0:00:35
2012-11-07 8:02:00,0:00:36
2012-11-07 8:02:00,0:03:03
2012-11-07 8:07:00,0:00:07
2012-11-07 8:08:00,0:00:08
2012-11-07 8:12:00,0:00:34
2012-11-07 8:12:00,0:00:44
2012-11-07 8:18:00,0:01:05
2012-11-07 8:28:00,0:01:05
2012-11-07 8:29:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 8:31:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 8:31:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 8:31:00,0:00:11
2012-11-07 8:32:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 8:32:00,0:27:26
2012-11-07 8:32:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 8:32:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 8:32:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 8:32:00,0:00:38
2012-11-07 8:33:00,0:00:35
2012-11-07 8:33:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 8:34:00,0:01:10
2012-11-07 8:35:00,0:09:44
2012-11-07 8:35:00,0:22:21
2012-11-07 8:35:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 8:35:00,0:21:42
2012-11-07 8:35:00,0:21:46
2012-11-07 8:35:00,0:21:46
2012-11-07 8:37:00,0:00:29
2012-11-07 8:38:00,0:00:29
2012-11-07 8:39:00,0:06:50
2012-11-07 8:39:00,0:08:23
2012-11-07 8:53:00,0:05:01
2012-11-07 8:53:00,0:05:05
2012-11-07 8:53:00,0:05:05
2012-11-07 8:57:00,0:01:04
2012-11-07 9:00:00,0:29:40
2012-11-07 9:01:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 9:01:00,0:01:27
2012-11-07 9:02:00,0:27:00
2012-11-07 9:03:00,0:26:18
2012-11-07 9:03:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 9:09:00,0:01:16
2012-11-07 9:12:00,0:02:53
2012-11-07 9:12:00,0:01:09
2012-11-07 9:12:00,0:27:27
2012-11-07 9:14:00,0:07:13
2012-11-07 9:14:00,0:07:18
2012-11-07 9:14:00,0:07:18
2012-11-07 9:18:00,0:11:39
2012-11-07 9:18:00,0:11:55
2012-11-07 9:18:00,0:00:16
2012-11-07 9:17:00,0:12:15
2012-11-07 9:18:00,0:00:48
2012-11-07 9:18:00,0:00:52
2012-11-07 9:18:00,0:00:52
2012-11-07 9:19:00,0:01:12
2012-11-07 9:21:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 9:22:00,0:02:41
2012-11-07 9:22:00,0:02:36
2012-11-07 9:22:00,0:02:49
2012-11-07 9:24:00,0:01:34
2012-11-07 9:25:00,0:06:10
2012-11-07 9:25:00,0:06:14
2012-11-07 9:25:00,0:06:14
2012-11-07 9:31:00,0:00:43
2012-11-07 9:33:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 9:33:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 9:33:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 9:33:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 9:33:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 9:33:00,0:05:57
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:06:28
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:06:53
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:00:35
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:01:04
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:01:04
2012-11-07 9:32:00,0:00:41
2012-11-07 9:36:00,0:00:27
2012-11-07 9:37:00,0:23:53
2012-11-07 9:38:00,0:01:51
2012-11-07 9:40:00,0:06:40
2012-11-07 9:40:00,0:06:44
2012-11-07 9:40:00,0:06:44
2012-11-07 9:44:00,0:01:19
2012-11-07 9:46:00,0:00:55
2012-11-07 9:46:00,0:02:01
2012-11-07 9:47:00,0:20:00
2012-11-07 9:47:00,0:02:22
2012-11-07 9:47:00,0:07:12
2012-11-07 9:47:00,0:02:22
2012-11-07 9:47:00,0:00:13
2012-11-07 9:48:00,0:00:41
2012-11-07 9:48:00,0:01:25
2012-11-07 9:50:00,0:01:24
2012-11-07 9:52:00,0:00:06
2012-11-07 9:54:00,0:00:06
2012-11-07 9:57:00,0:00:28
2012-11-07 9:57:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 9:57:00,0:00:48
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:00:06
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:00:06
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:00:06
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:00:06
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:00:06
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:06:49
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:07:19
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:07:38
2012-11-07 9:58:00,0:01:36
2012-11-07 9:59:00,0:00:59
2012-11-07 9:59:00,0:01:00
2012-11-07 10:00:00,0:17:43
2012-11-07 10:00:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 10:00:00,1:02:29
2012-11-07 10:01:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 10:01:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 10:01:00,0:00:52
2012-11-07 10:01:00,0:20:23
2012-11-07 10:01:00,0:01:09
2012-11-07 10:01:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 10:01:00,0:01:15
2012-11-07 10:02:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 10:02:00,0:00:36
2012-11-07 10:02:00,0:00:48
2012-11-07 10:02:00,0:21:49
2012-11-07 10:03:00,0:40:24
2012-11-07 10:04:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 10:04:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 10:04:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 10:04:00,0:05:59
2012-11-07 10:04:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 10:04:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 10:04:00,0:05:59
2012-11-07 10:03:00,0:06:20
2012-11-07 10:03:00,0:00:22
2012-11-07 10:06:00,0:20:35
2012-11-07 10:07:00,0:02:44
2012-11-07 10:08:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 10:09:00,0:00:29
2012-11-07 10:09:00,0:01:17
2012-11-07 10:10:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 10:11:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 10:12:00,0:01:43
2012-11-07 10:12:00,0:24:01
2012-11-07 10:12:00,0:24:04
2012-11-07 10:12:00,0:24:04
2012-11-07 10:12:00,0:01:23
2012-11-07 10:13:00,0:03:51
2012-11-07 10:13:00,0:03:40
2012-11-07 10:14:00,0:09:52
2012-11-07 10:16:00,0:13:33
2012-11-07 10:16:00,0:13:37
2012-11-07 10:16:00,0:13:37
2012-11-07 10:21:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 10:21:00,0:01:18
2012-11-07 10:21:00,0:01:18
2012-11-07 10:22:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 10:22:00,0:00:32
2012-11-07 10:22:00,0:00:32
2012-11-07 10:22:00,0:04:31
2012-11-07 10:22:00,0:00:57
2012-11-07 10:23:00,0:10:23
2012-11-07 10:24:00,0:01:20
2012-11-07 10:24:00,0:01:24
2012-11-07 10:24:00,0:01:24
2012-11-07 10:25:00,0:27:34
2012-11-07 10:28:00,0:00:49
2012-11-07 10:30:00,0:01:46
2012-11-07 10:30:00,0:01:51
2012-11-07 10:30:00,0:01:51
2012-11-07 10:30:00,0:01:01
2012-11-07 10:31:00,0:00:43
2012-11-07 10:31:00,0:15:08
2012-11-07 10:33:00,0:02:37
2012-11-07 10:35:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 10:35:00,0:01:24
2012-11-07 10:35:00,0:01:24
2012-11-07 10:37:00,0:02:07
2012-11-07 10:37:00,0:00:08
2012-11-07 10:38:00,0:00:10
2012-11-07 10:39:00,0:01:37
2012-11-07 10:39:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 10:39:00,0:01:53
2012-11-07 10:39:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 10:40:00,0:00:34
2012-11-07 10:41:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 10:41:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 10:41:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 10:41:00,0:02:20
2012-11-07 10:45:00,0:07:57
2012-11-07 10:51:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 10:51:00,0:00:56
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:01:12
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:01:44
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:00:31
2012-11-07 10:50:00,0:00:31
2012-11-07 10:49:00,0:03:05
2012-11-07 10:54:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 10:54:00,0:01:02
2012-11-07 10:54:00,0:01:02
2012-11-07 10:55:00,0:02:08
2012-11-07 10:56:00,0:00:33
2012-11-07 10:56:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 10:59:00,0:24:33
2012-11-07 10:59:00,0:24:37
2012-11-07 10:59:00,0:24:37
2012-11-07 11:00:00,0:29:41
2012-11-07 11:00:00,0:07:38
2012-11-07 11:00:00,0:00:51
2012-11-07 11:01:00,0:00:33
2012-11-07 11:02:00,0:28:12
2012-11-07 11:02:00,0:35:02
2012-11-07 11:02:00,0:35:05
2012-11-07 11:02:00,0:35:05
2012-11-07 11:02:00,0:21:29
2012-11-07 11:03:00,0:02:24
2012-11-07 11:03:00,0:02:28
2012-11-07 11:03:00,0:02:28
2012-11-07 11:03:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 11:04:00,0:34:28
2012-11-07 11:04:00,0:08:20
2012-11-07 11:04:00,0:01:01
2012-11-07 11:06:00,0:16:09
2012-11-07 11:08:00,0:00:50
2012-11-07 11:11:00,0:02:08
2012-11-07 11:14:00,0:01:22
2012-11-07 11:14:00,0:01:26
2012-11-07 11:14:00,0:01:26
2012-11-07 11:14:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 11:14:00,0:00:57
2012-11-07 11:14:00,0:00:57
2012-11-07 11:15:00,0:09:48
2012-11-07 11:15:00,0:11:10
2012-11-07 11:16:00,0:00:55
2012-11-07 11:18:00,0:00:48
2012-11-07 11:22:00,0:00:51
2012-11-07 11:22:00,0:00:51
2012-11-07 11:22:00,0:00:51
2012-11-07 11:22:00,0:01:16
2012-11-07 11:28:00,0:03:36
2012-11-07 11:29:00,0:13:18
2012-11-07 11:30:00,0:03:47
2012-11-07 11:30:00,0:20:44
2012-11-07 11:30:00,0:01:29
2012-11-07 11:32:00,0:00:39
2012-11-07 11:32:00,0:07:04
2012-11-07 11:35:00,0:02:04
2012-11-07 11:35:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 11:35:00,0:00:32
2012-11-07 11:35:00,0:00:32
2012-11-07 11:37:00,0:18:14
2012-11-07 11:37:00,0:18:14
2012-11-07 11:37:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 11:37:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 11:37:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 11:36:00,0:18:57
2012-11-07 11:37:00,0:24:10
2012-11-07 11:38:00,0:00:19
2012-11-07 11:38:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 11:38:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 11:38:00,0:01:29
2012-11-07 11:41:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 11:41:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 11:41:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 11:41:00,0:04:48
2012-11-07 11:41:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 11:41:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 11:41:00,0:04:48
2012-11-07 11:40:00,0:05:09
2012-11-07 11:41:00,0:01:41
2012-11-07 11:42:00,0:15:24
2012-11-07 11:42:00,0:15:30
2012-11-07 11:42:00,0:15:30
2012-11-07 11:59:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 11:59:00,0:00:31
2012-11-07 11:59:00,0:00:31
2012-11-07 12:00:00,0:08:56
2012-11-07 12:01:00,0:22:31
2012-11-07 12:02:00,0:00:26
2012-11-07 12:02:00,0:33:20
2012-11-07 12:03:00,0:33:45
2012-11-07 12:06:00,0:00:56
2012-11-07 12:18:00,0:00:55
2012-11-07 12:18:00,0:00:55
2012-11-07 12:18:00,0:01:04
2012-11-07 12:24:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 12:24:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 12:24:00,0:00:25
2012-11-07 12:25:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 12:25:00,0:01:08
2012-11-07 12:25:00,0:01:08
2012-11-07 12:26:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 12:26:00,0:00:54
2012-11-07 12:26:00,0:00:54
2012-11-07 12:29:00,0:00:11
2012-11-07 12:31:00,0:02:10
2012-11-07 12:31:00,0:12:35
2012-11-07 12:31:00,0:06:26
2012-11-07 12:46:00,0:00:34
2012-11-07 12:47:00,0:01:01
2012-11-07 12:47:00,0:01:24
2012-11-07 12:48:00,0:00:15
2012-11-07 12:48:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 12:48:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 12:48:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 12:50:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 12:50:00,0:00:32
2012-11-07 12:50:00,0:00:32
2012-11-07 12:55:00,0:01:30
2012-11-07 12:55:00,0:01:31
2012-11-07 12:55:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 12:55:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 12:55:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 12:54:00,0:02:13
2012-11-07 12:59:00,0:36:03
2012-11-07 13:00:00,0:09:42
2012-11-07 13:00:00,0:13:35
2012-11-07 13:01:00,0:18:08
2012-11-07 13:01:00,0:28:37
2012-11-07 13:02:00,0:01:26
2012-11-07 13:02:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 13:02:00,0:09:42
2012-11-07 13:03:00,0:04:53
2012-11-07 13:04:00,0:00:35
2012-11-07 13:12:00,0:14:28
2012-11-07 13:12:00,0:14:28
2012-11-07 13:12:00,0:14:42
2012-11-07 13:13:00,0:00:45
2012-11-07 13:14:00,0:01:27
2012-11-07 13:15:00,0:13:04
2012-11-07 13:14:00,0:13:08
2012-11-07 13:14:00,0:13:08
2012-11-07 13:14:00,0:15:32
2012-11-07 13:15:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 13:15:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 13:15:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 13:16:00,0:00:42
2012-11-07 13:16:00,0:01:04
2012-11-07 13:17:00,0:02:01
2012-11-07 13:22:00,0:00:12
2012-11-07 13:24:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 13:24:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 13:24:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 13:26:00,0:03:07
2012-11-07 13:27:00,0:00:41
2012-11-07 13:29:00,0:02:00
2012-11-07 13:30:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 13:32:00,0:09:24
2012-11-07 13:32:00,0:25:47
2012-11-07 13:32:00,0:25:50
2012-11-07 13:32:00,0:25:50
2012-11-07 13:33:00,0:03:53
2012-11-07 13:38:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 13:38:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 13:39:00,0:27:03
2012-11-07 13:39:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 13:39:00,0:01:02
2012-11-07 13:39:00,0:01:02
2012-11-07 13:40:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 13:42:00,0:06:23
2012-11-07 13:42:00,0:00:15
2012-11-07 13:42:00,0:00:15
2012-11-07 13:42:00,0:06:55
2012-11-07 13:41:00,0:07:15
2012-11-07 13:45:00,0:00:33
2012-11-07 13:45:00,0:00:35
2012-11-07 13:46:00,0:01:12
2012-11-07 13:51:00,0:01:55
2012-11-07 13:53:00,0:02:02
2012-11-07 13:55:00,0:00:08
2012-11-07 13:55:00,0:03:42
2012-11-07 13:56:00,0:01:32
2012-11-07 14:01:00,0:00:54
2012-11-07 14:01:00,0:09:24
2012-11-07 14:01:00,0:09:27
2012-11-07 14:01:00,0:09:27
2012-11-07 14:02:00,0:35:17
2012-11-07 14:02:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 14:02:00,0:35:48
2012-11-07 14:02:00,0:35:48
2012-11-07 14:02:00,0:01:00
2012-11-07 14:04:00,0:34:37
2012-11-07 14:04:00,0:34:37
2012-11-07 14:04:00,0:34:37
2012-11-07 14:05:00,0:04:38
2012-11-07 14:05:00,0:04:38
2012-11-07 14:05:00,0:04:43
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:31
2012-11-07 14:08:00,0:13:06
2012-11-07 14:08:00,0:13:06
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:01:15
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:01:16
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:14:39
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:34
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 14:06:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 14:07:00,0:11:06
2012-11-07 14:15:00,0:01:37
2012-11-07 14:15:00,0:01:53
2012-11-07 14:15:00,0:00:16
2012-11-07 14:14:00,0:02:19
2012-11-07 14:16:00,0:01:10
2012-11-07 14:19:00,0:04:45
2012-11-07 14:19:00,0:11:31
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:01:13
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:01:13
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:01:30
2012-11-07 14:21:00,0:01:43
2012-11-07 14:22:00,0:00:34
2012-11-07 14:23:00,0:03:41
2012-11-07 14:26:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 14:26:00,0:00:45
2012-11-07 14:26:00,0:00:45
2012-11-07 14:26:00,0:15:39
2012-11-07 14:28:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 14:28:00,0:02:04
2012-11-07 14:28:00,0:02:04
2012-11-07 14:30:00,0:08:36
2012-11-07 14:31:00,0:10:26
2012-11-07 14:43:00,0:01:16
2012-11-07 14:43:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 14:43:00,0:01:41
2012-11-07 14:57:00,0:00:21
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:03:41
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:03:42
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:00:04
2012-11-07 14:57:00,0:04:02
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:01:50
2012-11-07 14:58:00,0:01:50
2012-11-07 14:59:00,0:01:42
2012-11-07 14:59:00,0:01:46
2012-11-07 14:59:00,0:01:46
2012-11-07 14:59:00,0:19:45
2012-11-07 15:01:00,0:00:55
2012-11-07 15:02:00,0:00:10
2012-11-07 15:03:00,0:01:13
2012-11-07 15:04:00,0:42:23
2012-11-07 15:05:00,0:02:24
2012-11-07 15:05:00,0:00:36
2012-11-07 15:06:00,0:00:08
2012-11-07 15:06:00,0:00:41
2012-11-07 15:06:00,0:10:57
2012-11-07 15:06:00,0:11:00
2012-11-07 15:06:00,0:11:01
2012-11-07 15:13:00,0:01:42
2012-11-07 15:13:00,0:01:42
2012-11-07 15:13:00,0:00:22
2012-11-07 15:13:00,0:00:23
2012-11-07 15:13:00,0:00:23
2012-11-07 15:12:00,0:02:29
2012-11-07 15:15:00,0:00:19
2012-11-07 15:15:00,0:00:23
2012-11-07 15:15:00,0:00:23
2012-11-07 15:19:00,0:06:07
2012-11-07 15:22:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 15:21:00,0:01:00
2012-11-07 15:21:00,0:01:00
2012-11-07 15:27:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 15:27:00,0:00:00
2012-11-07 15:27:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 15:27:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 15:27:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 15:28:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 15:28:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 15:28:00,0:01:13
2012-11-07 15:30:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 15:30:00,0:00:33
2012-11-07 15:30:00,0:00:33
2012-11-07 15:30:00,0:13:31
2012-11-07 15:31:00,0:05:40
2012-11-07 15:31:00,0:05:43
2012-11-07 15:31:00,0:05:43
2012-11-07 15:35:00,0:18:18
2012-11-07 15:35:00,0:18:18
2012-11-07 15:35:00,0:18:18
2012-11-07 15:40:00,0:08:56
2012-11-07 15:40:00,0:08:59
2012-11-07 15:40:00,0:08:59
2012-11-07 15:46:00,0:18:07
2012-11-07 15:49:00,0:01:39
2012-11-07 15:49:00,0:01:40
2012-11-07 15:49:00,0:01:40
2012-11-07 15:48:00,0:01:59
2012-11-07 15:48:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 15:50:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 15:50:00,0:00:24
2012-11-07 15:50:00,0:01:17
2012-11-07 15:52:00,0:00:01
2012-11-07 15:52:00,0:01:24
2012-11-07 15:52:00,0:01:24
2012-11-07 15:52:00,0:01:43
2012-11-07 16:01:00,0:00:03
2012-11-07 16:01:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 16:01:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 16:02:00,0:00:34
2012-11-07 16:03:00,0:00:42
2012-11-07 16:05:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 16:05:00,0:00:27
2012-11-07 16:05:00,0:00:27
2012-11-07 16:05:00,0:00:37
2012-11-07 16:14:00,0:00:55
2012-11-07 16:14:00,0:00:56
2012-11-07 16:14:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 16:14:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 16:14:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 16:13:00,0:01:37
2012-11-07 16:16:00,0:01:01
2012-11-07 16:16:00,0:01:05
2012-11-07 16:16:00,0:01:05
2012-11-07 16:18:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 16:18:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 16:18:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 16:18:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 16:18:00,0:00:19
2012-11-07 16:17:00,0:00:52
2012-11-07 16:20:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 16:20:00,0:01:41
2012-11-07 16:20:00,0:01:41
2012-11-07 16:41:00,0:25:43
2012-11-07 16:41:00,0:25:44
2012-11-07 16:41:00,0:00:16
2012-11-07 16:41:00,0:00:16
2012-11-07 16:41:00,0:00:17
2012-11-07 16:41:00,0:26:16
2012-11-07 16:50:00,0:00:36
2012-11-07 16:50:00,0:23:05
2012-11-07 16:54:00,0:01:07
2012-11-07 16:55:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 16:55:00,0:00:02
2012-11-07 16:55:00,0:00:18
2012-11-07 16:59:00,0:01:08
2012-11-07 16:58:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 16:58:00,0:00:51
2012-11-07 16:58:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 16:58:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 16:58:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 16:58:00,0:00:05
2012-11-07 16:57:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 16:57:00,0:00:30
2012-11-07 16:57:00,0:01:22
2012-11-07 16:57:00,0:02:55
2012-11-07 17:07:00,0:00:06
2012-11-07 17:07:00,0:02:47
2012-11-07 17:12:00,0:00:09
2012-11-07 17:12:00,0:00:10
2012-11-07 17:12:00,0:00:10
2012-11-07 17:12:00,0:00:28
2012-11-07 17:13:00,0:00:43
2012-11-07 17:14:00,0:02:13
2012-11-07 17:22:00,0:05:11
2012-11-07 17:23:00,0:00:27
2012-11-07 17:28:00,0:00:07
2012-11-07 17:38:00,0:01:25
2012-11-07 17:46:00,0:01:19
2012-11-07 20:34:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 20:34:00,0:00:36
2012-11-07 20:34:00,0:00:37
2012-11-07 22:49:00,0:00:20
2012-11-07 22:49:00,0:00:29
2012-11-07 22:49:00,0:00:30
```

Comment: Good question, will add that.

Answer (score 3):

For each call in the log, count the calls that are active at that call_datetime, then find the maximum:

```
SELECT MAX(calls) FROM
(SELECT cl1.call_datetime, COUNT(*) AS calls
 FROM call_log cl1
 INNER JOIN call_log cl2
 ON cl1.call_datetime
 BETWEEN cl2.call_datetime  AND ADDTIME(cl2.call_datetime, cl2.call_length)
 GROUP BY cl1.call_id) AS counts;
```

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/628fb/24)

Demo does not include all your data(because it is not allowed on sqlfiddle due to more than 8000 characters) but some sample data

It shows the maximum count of concurrent calls

```
SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM
(SELECT cl1.b, COUNT(*) AS cnt
 FROM calls cl1
 INNER JOIN calls cl2
 ON cl1.b
 BETWEEN cl2.b  AND ADDTIME(cl2.b, cl2.c)
 GROUP BY cl1.a) AS counts;
```

and all possible counts.

```
SELECT cnt FROM
(SELECT cl1.b, COUNT(*) AS cnt
 FROM calls cl1
 INNER JOIN calls cl2
 ON cl1.b
 BETWEEN cl2.b  AND ADDTIME(cl2.b, cl2.c)
 GROUP BY cl1.a) AS counts;
```

Comment: Answer is highly influence by Terje D. However it is bit extended and demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from   
(
   select count(*), time(call_datetime) t0 from call_log    
   group by time(call_datetime)   
)  as q0 order by q0.t0 desc;
```

Change the `group by` to use `date, time, hour, min, sec`, etc.

Comment: This will only count the number of calls being started at a given time. It will not include active calls started prior to that time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding +1 for each start of call, and -1 for each end, then just get cumulative sum of that +1/-1 column

***Convert the calldate if needed or use your format:

```
set @from:='2015-02-01';
set @to:='2015-03-01';
set @csum:=0;
SELECT DT,CallCount, (@csum := @csum + CallCount) as cumulative_sum
FROM 
(select calldate AS DT, 1 AS CallCount
 from cdr
 where calldate between @from and @to

 union all

 select ADDDATE(calldate,INTERVAL duration SECOND) AS DT, -1 AS CallCount
 from cdr 
 where calldate between @from and @to
  ) Calls
ORDER BY 1 asc;
```

I've gave one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420744/mysql-query-peak-concurrent-calls-cdr-data)