# multiple MySQL queries to a single insert

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to perform a number of MySQL queries and to write the results as a single line to a different database and table.

So this works

```
INSERT INTO bridgedb.stats (longestcall, totalmins, totalconfs)
SELECT
(SELECT MAX(duration) AS longestcall FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),

(SELECT SUM(duration) AS totalmins FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

and this works

```
INSERT INTO bridgedb.stats (date, peakchan)
SELECT
  `calldate`,
  MAX(concurrent)+1 AS peakcount
FROM (
    SELECT
      DATE(a.calldate) as calldate,
      COUNT(b.uniqueid) AS concurrent
    FROM asteriskcdr.cdr AS a, asteriskcdr.cdr AS b
    WHERE  
      a.calldate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY
      AND (
        (a.calldate<=b.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate)+a.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate))
        OR (b.calldate<=a.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate)+b.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate))
      )
      AND a.uniqueid>b.uniqueid
    GROUP BY a.uniqueid
  ) AS baseview
GROUP BY calldate;
```

But this doesn't work

```
INSERT INTO bridgedb.stats (date, peakchan, longestcall, totalmins, totalconfs)
SELECT
(SELECT
      `calldate`,
      MAX(concurrent)+1 AS peakcount
    FROM (
        SELECT
          DATE(a.calldate) as calldate,
          COUNT(b.uniqueid) AS concurrent
        FROM asteriskcdr.cdr AS a, asteriskcdr.cdr AS b
        WHERE  
          a.calldate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
          AND (
            (a.calldate<=b.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate)+a.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate))
            OR (b.calldate<=a.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate)+b.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate))
          )
          AND a.uniqueid>b.uniqueid
        GROUP BY a.uniqueid
      ) AS baseview
    GROUP BY calldate),

(SELECT MAX(duration) AS longestcall FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),

(SELECT SUM(duration) AS totalmins FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

I get an error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Does anyone know how I can make this work for all the queries?

Comment: you first subquery projects 2 columns *inside* the subquery itself, but not outside. The 2 columns you select cannot be used from the outside, you have to do differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using session variables or abstract it away into a stored procedure, something like -

First:

```
SELECT
  @calldate:=`calldate`,
  @peakchan:=MAX(concurrent)+1
FROM (
  ...
) AS baseview
GROUP BY calldate
```

Second:

```
SELECT @longestcall:=MAX(duration) FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Third:

```
SELECT @totalmins:=SUM(duration)  FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Fourth:

```
SELECT @totalconfs:=COUNT(*) FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

And finally

```
INSERT INTO bridgedb.stats (date, peakchan, longestcall, totalmins, totalconfs)
VALUES (@calldate, @peakchan, @longestcall, @totalmins, @totalconfs)
```

BTW: It is not a good idea to call a column `date`.

**EDIT**

Ofcourse you need to make sure, those queries run in the same session to use session variables. This is the default when run with a single DB connection in PHP

**EDIT 2**

To handle periods without activity, you can

- either prefix this with `SELECT @calldate:=DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY), @peakchan:=0, @longestcall:=0, @totalmins:=0, @totalconfs:=0;` (record with defaults created)
- or stop after the first query, if @calldate is NULL (no record created)

**EDIT 3**

This works for me:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ReportYesterday()
BEGIN
  DECLARE calldate DATE;
  DECLARE peakchan, longestcall, totalmins, totalconfs INT;

SELECT
  @calldate:=`calldate`,
  @peakchan:=MAX(concurrent)+1
FROM (
       SELECT
          DATE(a.calldate) as calldate,
          COUNT(b.uniqueid) AS concurrent
        FROM asteriskcdr.cdr AS a, asteriskcdr.cdr AS b
        WHERE  
          a.calldate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
          AND (
            (a.calldate<=b.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate)+a.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate))
            OR (b.calldate<=a.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate)+b.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate))
          )
          AND a.uniqueid>b.uniqueid
        GROUP BY a.uniqueid) AS baseview
GROUP BY calldate
;

-- EDIT 4 IS THE FOLLOWING LINE 

IF @calldate IS NOT NULL THEN

  SELECT @longestcall:=MAX(duration) FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ;

  SELECT @totalmins:=SUM(duration)  FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ;

  SELECT @totalconfs:=COUNT(*) FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ;

  INSERT INTO bridgedb.stats (date, peakchan, longestcall, totalmins, totalconfs)
  VALUES (@calldate, @peakchan, @longestcall, @totalmins, @totalconfs)
  ;

END IF;

END
;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

followed by

```
CALL ReportYesterday();
```

Comment: Yes this works well when there is data to report, many thanks. If there is no ativity for that period I get ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'logdate' cannot be null so I am expecting to set the default values in the database to `0` but for the date (changed to logdate :-)) I would like to set it to NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY. I was trying this but it doesn't work SET @calldate = IFNULL(@calldate, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) any ideas?

Comment: I can't test right now but if I set the default variables first does this not get over written by the queries? Would it be better to check at the end with an ifnull. The final result should be if there is no data write a line with the date and the rest of the stats zero

Comment: The defaults will only be overwritten if applicable - a NULL date will not overwrite the default, as the `@calldate:=calldate` is never taken (no rows)

Comment: Yes this works well (thanks again) if I drop the program into mysql via ssh. However I can't create a stored procedure or a scheduled event, I get an error complying about line 3, I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes your right. Many thanks for your kind support it is much appreciated and again I have learned a lot.

Comment: OK last adjustment. when I call the procedure from the mysql command line it works great. When I run it from the sql tab in phpmyadmin I get #1048 - Column 'logdate' cannot be null and when I schedule the event I assume I get the same result as no data is written. Also when I call the stored procedure from the command line the data it writes are defaults not the date and `0` which I can see we are not setting

Comment: Small update. An error in the schema was stopping the insert when scheduled, this now works. I have added default values to the fields which takes care of some of it but the two time fields always come back as `NULL` when there is no data. any thoughts on how to re introduce the select@

Comment: I included an `IF ... END IF;` in the stored procedure, that should fix this (I simply forgot in the first run). Mind, that if the keys on `bridgedb.stats` are allright (essentially unique key on date), a `REPLACE` instead of an `INSERT` might be more robust.

Comment: I've been testing and find that the calldate always returns NULL. I can't see the error can you?

Comment: OK if I take out this line I get an output   DECLARE calldate DATE; but I get yesterday and today's data returned

Answer (score 0):

You must build a (valid) SELECT query which returns all rows. Your former SELECT was not valid. This one should work:

```
INSERT INTO bridgedb.stats (date, peakchan, longestcall, totalmins, totalconfs)
SELECT
      `calldate`,
      MAX(concurrent)+1 AS peakcount,
(SELECT MAX(duration) AS longestcall FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
(SELECT SUM(duration) AS totalmins FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bridgedb.log WHERE `start` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    FROM (
        SELECT
          DATE(a.calldate) as calldate,
          COUNT(b.uniqueid) AS concurrent
        FROM asteriskcdr.cdr AS a, asteriskcdr.cdr AS b
        WHERE  
          a.calldate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
          AND (
            (a.calldate<=b.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate)+a.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate))
            OR (b.calldate<=a.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate)+b.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate))
          )
          AND a.uniqueid>b.uniqueid
        GROUP BY a.uniqueid
      ) AS baseview
    GROUP BY calldate;
```